# Can't delete div's with new added buttons

Tags: javascript, events

after I keep creating new DIVs with my javascript functions, the new ones don't delete themselves.

My codes creates a post it div which gives info about title, author, and pages, and a X button that when you press it, it deletes it.
It works for my first 4 HTML examples, but not with the newly added divs from javascript.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.right');
let removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');
let removeButtonsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(removeButtons);
let bookNum = 4;

function addBook() {
    const titleAdd = document.getElementById('title-add').value;
    const readAdd = document.getElementById('read-add').value;
    const totalAdd = document.getElementById('total-add').value;


    if (titleAdd == '' || readAdd == '' || totalAdd == '') {
        alert('Complete all of the boxes');
        return;
    }   else if (readAdd > totalAdd) {
        alert('why are you lying? =[[');
        return;
    }

    const book = document.createElement('div');
    book.classList.add('book');
    container.appendChild(book);

    const xButton = document.createElement('button');
    xButton.classList.add('remove');
    book.appendChild(xButton);
    xButton.innerHTML = 'X';

    const title = document.createElement('h2');
    book.appendChild(title);
    title.innerHTML = titleAdd;

    const author = document.createElement('h3');
    book.appendChild(author);
    author.innerHTML = document.getElementById('author-add').value;

    const pages = document.createElement('h3');
    book.appendChild(pages);
    const pagesNumber = readAdd + '/' + totalAdd;
    pages.classList.add('page-num')
    pages.innerHTML = pagesNumber; 

    bookNum++;
    removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');
    removeButtonsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(removeButtons);
}

const button = document.querySelector('.add');
button.onclick = addBook;



removeButtonsArray.forEach(removeButton => removeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const remove = removeButtonsArray.indexOf(removeButton);
    removeButtonsArray.splice(remove, 1);
    document.querySelector('.book').remove();
    bookNum--;
}));
```

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="title-add">
                <h2>Title:</h2>
                <input type="text" id="title-add" name="title-add" max="30">
            </div>
            <div class="author-add">
                <h2>Author:</h2>
                <input type="text" id="author-add" name="author-add" max="30">
            </div>
            <div class="pages">
                <div class="pages-read">
                    <h3>Pages read:</h3>
                    <input type="number" id="read-add" min="0" name="read">
                </div>
                <div class="pages-total">
                    <h3>Total pages:</h3>
                    <input type="number" id="total-add" min="1" name="total">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="add">Add book</button>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="book">
                <button class="remove">X</button>
                <h2 class="title">muie</h2    >
                <h3 class="author">Csokmai Robert123</h3>
                <h3 class="page-num">31/316</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="book">
                <button class="remove">X</button>
                <h2>muie</h2    >
                <h3>Csokmai Robert</h3>
                <h3 class="page-num">31/316</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="book">
                <button class="remove">X</button>
                <h2>muie</h2    >
                <h3>Csokmai Robert</h3>
                <h3 class="page-num">31/316</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="book">
                <button class="remove">X</button>
                <h2>muie</h2    >
                <h3>Csokmai Robert</h3>
                <h3 class="page-num">31/316</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried everything but I just don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problems:

There are a few Problems with your code:

1. Delete function doesn't actually work, because every time you are just removing the first element which has `book` class. `document.querySelector('.book').remove();`
2. The reason the Delete button for Dynamically added books was not working is because this bit of code `removeButtonsArray.forEach(removeButton => removeButton.addEventListener` was executed only on first execution. So, newly added buttons weren't getting the Event Listener registered for them.

## Solutions:

1. Delete functionality can be easily handled by targeting the `parentElement` of the Delete Button which was clicked.
2. For the Dynamically added Books' Delete Functionality, We need to register the click Event Listener for each one of them during creation.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.right');
let removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');
let bookNum = 4;

function addBook() {
  const titleAdd = document.getElementById('title-add').value;
  const readAdd = document.getElementById('read-add').value;
  const totalAdd = document.getElementById('total-add').value;


  if (titleAdd == '' || readAdd == '' || totalAdd == '') {
    alert('Complete all of the boxes');
    return;
  } else if (readAdd > totalAdd) {
    alert('why are you lying? =[[');
    return;
  }

  const book = document.createElement('div');
  book.classList.add('book');
  container.appendChild(book);

  const xButton = document.createElement('button');
  xButton.classList.add('remove');
  book.appendChild(xButton);
  xButton.innerHTML = 'X';

  const title = document.createElement('h2');
  book.appendChild(title);
  title.innerHTML = titleAdd;

  const author = document.createElement('h3');
  book.appendChild(author);
  author.innerHTML = document.getElementById('author-add').value;

  const pages = document.createElement('h3');
  book.appendChild(pages);
  const pagesNumber = readAdd + '/' + totalAdd;
  pages.classList.add('page-num')
  pages.innerHTML = pagesNumber;

  bookNum++;

  // Adding Click Event to new Books Delete Button
  xButton.addEventListener("click", removeBook);
}

const button = document.querySelector('.add');
button.onclick = addBook;

// Function for Removing Book
function removeBook(e) {
  // Since we are getting the Delete Buttons event as Frunction Argument
  // We can get access to it's parentElement i.e., the target Book Div
  e.target.parentElement.remove();
  bookNum--;
}

removeButtons.forEach(removeButton => removeButton.addEventListener('click', removeBook));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="title-add">
      <h2>Title:</h2>
      <input type="text" id="title-add" name="title-add" max="30">
    </div>
    <div class="author-add">
      <h2>Author:</h2>
      <input type="text" id="author-add" name="author-add" max="30">
    </div>
    <div class="pages">
      <div class="pages-read">
        <h3>Pages read:</h3>
        <input type="number" id="read-add" min="0" name="read">
      </div>
      <div class="pages-total">
        <h3>Total pages:</h3>
        <input type="number" id="total-add" min="1" name="total">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="add">Add book</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="book">
      <button class="remove">X</button>
      <h2 class="title">muie</h2>
      <h3 class="author">Csokmai Robert123</h3>
      <h3 class="page-num">31/316</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <button class="remove">X</button>
      <h2>muie</h2>
      <h3>Csokmai Robert</h3>
      <h3 class="page-num">31/317</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <button class="remove">X</button>
      <h2>muie</h2>
      <h3>Csokmai Robert</h3>
      <h3 class="page-num">31/315</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <button class="remove">X</button>
      <h2>muie</h2>
      <h3>Csokmai Robert</h3>
      <h3 class="page-num">31/314</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```